# add a line of same height as floated column with :before

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a line which would be the same height as a floated column, next to it using :before.

I tried like this but it does span border doesn't span the whole height of the column.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
   <a href="#"><img src="../img/spv/more-ideas/more-ideas3.jpg" / alt=""></a>
       <div class="product-details">
           <a href="#">Outfit ansehen &raquo;</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.col-xs-12{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
 }

.col-xs-12:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the `.col-xs-12` because that's one of the default bootstrap grid selectors and it might mess up the entire structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using height `100%` against a parent with unspecified height, seeing as you are absolutely positioning use `top` and `bottom` values:

```
.col-xs-12{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
 }

.col-xs-12:before{
      content:"";
      display:block;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      border-left:1px solid #ccc;
      position:absolute;
}
```

As noted, however, you should avoid 'extending' the default bootstrap classes. Add another class to the column and use this instead. Incidentally, if you are only using this to apply a border- why not simply do so on the column itself?

Comment: because it needs a bit of distance away from the column like a bit of padding 3% for example